# testing with minitest capybara rails link not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, minitest

I'm currently testing with minitest capybara and I got an error on one of my tests

```
Unable to find link or button "Edit Profile"
```

here is my test

```
require "test_helper"

feature "as a student I want a working user system so grade = good" do
  scenario "users can update profile" do
    dude_sign_up
    dude_log_in
    click_on "Edit Profile"
    click_on "Update"
    page.must_have_content "Profile was successfully updated"
  end
end
```

the two helper methods for test helper

```
def dude_sign_up
  visit new_user_path
  fill_in "Name", with: 'thedude'
  fill_in "Email", with: "dude@dudecool.com"
  fill_in "Password", with: 'password'
  fill_in "Password confirmation", with: 'password'
  click_on "Sign Up"
end

def dude_log_in
  visit posts_path
  fill_in "Email", with: "dude@dudecool.com"
  fill_in "Password", with: 'password'
  click_on "Log In"
end
```

and if its needed my here is my _nav that I have rendered in application.html.erb between  and above the yield

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><%= link_to 'Home', root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'About', about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "The Blog", posts_path %></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Registration<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <% if current_user %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_user_path(current_user) %></td>
          <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Log out", logout_path %></li>
          <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to 'Sign Up', signup_path %></a></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Log In', login_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

it works fine if I just click on everything and go through it. I was not using fixtures is that the cause of my problem?

Comment: Are you sure the user is being successfully logged in?

Comment: ya because I ran another test to see if the logged in flash message came up and it did, i mean the test passed

Answer (score 1):

When Capybara looks for an element, it will only consider elements that are visible to the user.

Given the naming in your page, I am guessing that "Edit Profile" is not visible when the user first logs in. To see the link, the user likely needs to click the "Registration" link first.

Capybara needs to perform the same workflow. Try adding a `click_on "Registration"`:

```
scenario "users can update profile" do
  dude_sign_up
  dude_log_in
  click_on "Registration"
  click_on "Edit Profile"
  click_on "Update"
  page.must_have_content "Profile was successfully updated"
end
```